# Set Youtube Data API key on Rails using Javascript/jQuery/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, youtube-data-api

I am trying to do exactly the same as this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vH2eZAM30s&feature=youtu.be) on Rails but I am stuck at a point (see at 1:40) whether I need to specify  in application.html.erb in different format or there is any other way to do it.

First of all, after I have obtained authorisation credentials through creating a project in the google developers console, I began to first proceeded to follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdqsiFw74Jk). This was fairly easy and I had no problem with it as this tutorial specifies the key in every method or call. (see at 13:30).

However, (www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vH2eZAM30s&feature=youtu.be) when I started learning this second tutorial, I found that the tutorial approached requesting an API call slightly differently from the first tutorial. It set the api key in init() function and onload it with the script file and not specifying the key in methods and calling api requests.

1. developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps
2. developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

I looked up these guides but none of them gave me hints to follow the second tutorial on Rails.

How can I implement the second tutorial on Rails and What are the differences between the methods of setting the api key used in the first and second tutorial??